# Snowflake Stream created using SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS parameter raising error on selection

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been using `SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS` parameter in Snowflake when creating a new Stream on a table and it's always worked fine.

For some reason, the stream created in one of the tables is raising an error when some select statement is run against it.

```
Time travel data is not available for table [...]. The requested time is either beyond the allowed time travel period or before the object creation time
```

All the tables have time travel enabled and the statement I use to create the streams are something like:

```
create or replace stream <database>.<schema>.<stream>
on table <database>.<schema>.<table> SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS = TRUE;
```

Does anyone know if SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS is somehow related to time travel? If yes, what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

It should be related to the recent behaviour change on Time Travel:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Time-Travel-Queries-Beyond-Data-Retention-Period-Will-Fail-Pending

**Previous:**

If the historical version and the current version of a table were identical, queries beyond the table’s Time Travel data retention period could have completed successfully.

**Currently:**

If a query is beyond the Time Travel data retention period for a table, the query fails. This change ensures the semantics for Time Travel are consistent and produces predictable query results regardless of when a table was last modified.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know if this change can impact Streams somehow when using SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS?

Comment: Previously created streams? If you already consumed data from a previously created stream, then they should be OK.

Comment: No, in this case Im creating new streams on a table with historical data. I expect that all data from historical table will be inside the stream when I create it